# Using matrices to calculate fibonacci?

Tags: matrices, fibonacci-numbers

I have been told a couple of times it possible to calculate the fibonacci sequence much quicker using matrices but I never understood/they never elaborated. Would somebody be able to show how this technique works?

Comment: Or just use $F_n = \frac{\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$ where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342096/fibonacci-and-the-algebraic-expression-x2-x-1/342117#342117

Answer (score 5):

Using the recursion $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$ and the initial $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}^{\large n}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n+1}\\F_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
F_n=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}^{\large n}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

We can use the Jordan decomposition
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac1{\sqrt5}\begin{bmatrix}
-1/\phi&\phi\\1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/\phi&0\\0&\phi
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&\phi\\1&1/\phi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to get that
$$
\begin{align}
F_n
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/\phi&0\\0&\phi
\end{bmatrix}^{\large n}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\1
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\phi^n-(-1/\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: To turn this into a «quicker way» one needs to be smart about computing the matrix powers, though.

Comment: So you are saying to calculate f(7) I need to multiply the {(1,1),(1,0)} matrice by itself 7 times and then multiply the result with (1,0)? Sorry its been a while since I used matrices.

Comment: You diagonalize the matrix so then, computing the $n$-th power is easy and you get it back in the right basis with two matrix multiplications.

Comment: No, you can [diagonalize the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_diagonalization#Diagonalization).

Comment: You can also compute it using the binary algorithm for (matrix) powers: to find $M^7$, first find $M^2$, then $M^4=(M^2)^2$, and finally $M^7=M\cdot M^2\cdot M^4$, with a total of four (matrix) multiplications.  (This can be translated directly into a recurrence for $F_{2n}$ and $F_{2n+1}$ in terms of $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$.)  This approach (which clearly should be better-known!) takes $O(\log n)$ multiplications to find $F_n$, similarly to the explicit formula, but has the strong advantage of using only integer operations rather than needing $\phi$ to high precision.

Comment: Doesn’t diagonalizing the matrix and calculating the $n$-th powers of the eigenvalues amount to the same thing as using the (?) well-known closed formula for the Fibs?

Comment: @Lubin: yes, it does. I have just added that to my answer.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, you don't need to compute using high precision: since phi generates a quadratic extension of the rationals, you can compute there (and then this amounts more or less to the same thing as computing powers of matrix, but a different matrix)